# How to keep existing database on app update?

Tags: iphone

I have an iPhone app that use an Sqlite database to store some data and some user configurations. The problem that I'm having is that when I submit an update of my application, the existing database on the user installation  is overwrite with the empty database and the users lost their configurations. I'm sure it can not be too difficult to avoid this, but I don't know how to do it.

This is my code of the method that create the copy of the db:

```
// Creates a writable copy of the bundled default database in the application Documents directory.
- (void)createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded {
    // First, test for existence.
    BOOL success;
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *error;
    NSString *writableDBPath = [self databasePath];
    success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:writableDBPath];
    if (!success) {
        // The writable database does not exist, so copy the default to the appropriate location.
        //NSLog(dbName);
        NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:dbName];
        success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:writableDBPath error:&error];
        if (!success) {
            NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
    }
}
```

This method is called form:

```
- (BOOL)openDatabase {
    BOOL success = true;
    if (!database) {
        [self createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded];
        if (sqlite3_open([[self databasePath] UTF8String], &database) != SQLITE_OK) {
            success = false;
            // Even though the open failed, call close to properly clean up resources.
            sqlite3_close(database);
            NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to open database with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        }
    }
    return success;
}


- (NSString*)databasePath {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:dbName];
    return path;
}
```

Maybe I forgot something in my code?

Can some one help me to solve this out? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about copying the sqlite database from your main bundle to the application's document directory, but  only if it does not already exist?

Comment: Joseph, thank you for your answer, I think you are right and that´s what I need, but I can´t get it working. I have added the code that I use to create the db copy. Thanks.

Comment: What happens exactly? Please, on a side note, take notice of the fact that BOOL should be YES or NO, not true or false in Objective-C.

Comment: Emphasis on should, most people I know use it that way. So if I go through code, I would look for YES rather than true...

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Core Data, or using sqlite - you are probibly storing your data in the "Documents" directory. This will *not* be wiped-out when updating your app.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about sqlite databases, except that they are in-memory databases. It is not possible to 'keep' the in-memory databases. You have two options:

1) find a way to configure your sqlite to use a file instead of running in-memory (I don't know if this is possible, I looked but couldn't find a way quickly)

2) switch to a different database provider. If the pc is yours, you can install xampp or wamp (lamp on linux), containing a pre-configured, ready-to-run MySql database.

A final way would be to temporarily store the sqlite data when exiting and then reload it on startup, but that doesn't seem very optimal!

If you don't really need a database, you could also consider alternate storing such as xml or a flatfile

Comment: sqlite databases on the iPhone are files with an .sqlite extension. You can store them in the file system. Also, this question was iPhone specific, I think you must have overlooked that.